# How to invoke function of multiple arguments with HList?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Suppose I have an `HList` of type `A::B::C::HNil` and a function `(A, B, C) => D`

```
val hlist: A::B::C::HNil = ???
def foo(a: A, b: B, c: C): D = ???
```

Now I need a funciton `A::B::C::HNil => D`, which uses `foo` to return `D`.

```
def bar(hslist: A::B::C::HNil): D = ???
```

How would you implement `bar` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this a little more directly using Shapeless's `FnToProduct`, which provides `toProduct` syntax for converting a `FunctionN` into a `Function1` taking an `HList`:

```
import shapeless._, syntax.std.function._

type A = String
type B = Symbol
type C = Int
type D = List[String]

val hlist: A :: B :: C :: HNil = "foo" :: 'x :: 1 :: HNil

def foo(a: A, b: B, c: C): D = List.fill(c)(a + b)

def bar(hslist: A :: B :: C :: HNil): D = (foo _).toProduct.apply(hslist)
```

In many cases you probably wouldn't even want a separate `bar` definition.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Shapeless conversion from `HList` to `Tuple`, and use `Function.tupled` with your original function :

```
def sum(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b

def sumHList(hlist: Int :: Int :: HNil) = {
  val tupledSum = Function.tupled(sum _)
  tupledSum(hlist.tupled)
}

def sumHList2(hlist: Int :: Int :: HNil) = hlist.head + hlist.tail.head

sum(1, 2)
sumHList(1 :: 2 :: HNil)
sumHList2(1 :: 2 :: HNil)
// result from all three = 3
```